# Custom Range label in ng2-datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng2-datepicker

I want to change Custom Range label in ng2-datepicker from 'Custom Range' to 'XYZ'. But not able to find a solution or selector.

Comment: can you share ur code with stackblitz url

Comment: @dev.skas, a Stack Snippet would be better than an off-site URL

Comment: good old SO status abuse, of closing the question even with the upvote it has got and thinking that OP is dumb. Further details could have been asked!!
It is a freaking valid question!!